# How to identify duplicate values in excel cells and list them in another column using python?

Tags: excel, python-3.x

I just started python programming and i have been given an excel task. I have to identify duplicate values in a column in excel(it has around 850 rows) and list them in a new column. I am brand new to python therefore have no idea on how to execute this task. It would be very helpful if someone can share on how to start this or any methods in solving this task. A sample code would also be very helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas`, do something like:

```
import pandas as pd 

# let's assume this is our data which will be read from the excel
rows = [ ( 'a' , 'b' , { 'a' , 'b' } ) , ( 'b' , 'c' , { 'b' , 'c' } ) 
    ( 'b' , 'a' , { 'a' , 'b' } ) ] 
columns = [ 'x' , 'y' , 'z' ] 

# create a dataframe (like a table in excel)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records( rows , columns = columns) 

# you'll need to use: "pd.read_excel('my_excel_fle')" to read the file    

>> df

x  y       z
0  a  b  {b, a}
1  b  c  {b, c}
2  b  a  {b, a}

# now, put the columns which you want to find duplicates of in another column
df["dup_clmns"] = df.z.apply(lambda x: tuple(x))

>>df

x  y      z      dup_clmns

0  a  b  {b, a}  (b, a)
1  b  c  {b, c}  (b, c)
2  b  a  {b, a}  (b, a)

#now use "duplicates" or "drop_duplicates" (or whatever you want)
df.drop_duplicates(subset="dup_clmns", keep="first") # will remove duplicates of (x,y) columns

df.duplicated(subset="dup_clmns")
# will show duplicate rows based on the columns you choose
```